invoke logic from custom annotation on Spring Service
i'am trying to use custom annotation, which validation logic with reflection should be invoked automaticaly
import jakarta.validation.Constraint;
import jakarta.validation.Payload;

import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;
import static java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME;

@Constraint(validatedBy = ConfigValidator.class)
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
public @interface CheckTool {
    String usecaseFile();
    String message() default "wrong configuration";

    Class<?>[] groups() default {};

    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
}

and  the ConfigValidator looks like  this:
@Slf4j
@Component
public class ConfigValidator implements ConstraintValidator<CheckTool, Class<?>> {
private final Reflections reflections = new Reflections();

@Override
public boolean isValid(Class<?> value, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
//do some reflection stuff
}

}
And use is on my Spring-Service:
import jakarta.validation.Valid;

@Slf4j
@Valid
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@CheckToolForUsecase(usecaseFile = "my-config.json")
public class MyUsecase implements Usecase<MyTool> {
      //some methods
}

I'am expecting, that my code "isValid" from ConfigValidator gonna be executed, before i execute any method from "MyUsecase", but it does not work.
Why?
I'am using Jacarta Validation API 3.0 for this, but maybe, it is a wrong approach.
I want to achive, that on runtime with my custom-annotation some reflection-logik gonna be executed, before implemented methods.
